# HTML5 validation with a link and angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, validation

I have a simple form broken down into 3 sections. In the first section I collect First Name, Last Name and Email.

I am trying to use `type="email"` and `required` to provide validation feedback however im not using `input submit` until the last section of the form.

The form is broken into three section each section is only seen once the user clicks

```
<a ui-sref="form.select" class="btn btn-block btn-info" >
            Next Section <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
        </a>
```

I would like this click to trigger the validation that the way submit usually would.

Even disable this button until the user fills out the fields.

**Here is the full form code**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="first-name">First Name*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Fname" placeholder="Enter first name" ng-model="formData.Fname" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="last-name">Last Name*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Lname" placeholder="Enter last name" ng-model="formData.Lname" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email*</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address" ng-model="formData.email" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <a ui-sref="form.select" class="btn btn-block btn-info" >
            Next Section <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**QUESTION**

So my question, How to get the HTML 5 validation working on the button click, and how to disable button until fields correctly populated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the next section link to a `<button>` and use `ng-disabled`. `ng-disabled` does not work with `<a>` elements.
Either just write all conditions in `ng-disabled` or if it gets too long/complicated write a controller function to check.

```
<button ui-sref="form.select" ng-disabled="myform.first_name.$invalid || ....">
    Next Section 
</button>

<button ui-sref="form.select" ng-disabled="isButtonDisabled()">
    Next Section
</button>
```

If you have to use `<a>`, you will have to disable the link by yourself. For example:

```
.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

<a ng-click="disabled()" ng-class="{disabled: addInviteesDisabled()}">Add</a>

$scope.disabled = function() {
  if($scope.addInviteesDisabled) { return false;}
}
```

Comment: I can use button that is not a problem, Ill look into the use of ng-disabled="myform.first_name.$invalid || ...." as i think this is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the button until all fields are not inserted with valid data the try this one

```
<a ui-sref="form.select" class="btn btn-block btn-info" ng-
 disabled="formData.$invalid" >Next Section <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: im afraid this dose not work, even if the fields are populated its still disabled

Comment: instead of using 'anchor(<a>') tag use button because on button the above code is working nicely
<button ng-model="btn" ng-disabled="formData.$invalid" class="btn btn-block btn-info">NEXT Section</button>

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as a reference:

```
 <form name="upSign">

        First Name:
          <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter your first name" ng-model="user.first_name" required>


      Last Name:
          <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter your last name" ng-model="user.last_name" required>


      Email:
          <input type="email" name="mailId" ng-model="user.email_id" placeholder="Enter your Email" required>

    </form>

    <p ng-show="upSign.firstName.$invalid || upSign.mailId.$invalid || upSign.lastName.$invalid" style="color: red">*  Invalid</p>


    <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-disabled="upSign.firstName.$invalid || upSign.mailId.$invalid || upSign.lastName.$invalid || upSign.firstName.$untouched || upSign.mailId.$untouched || upSign.lastName.$untouched" ng-click="register()">Register Me</button>
```

Comment: This dose not work as it triggers submit rather than the next section

Comment: But how will it trigger submit if it is disabled?